# Cant explain why page wont work in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

At the top of this page: http://andrew-muir.com/search/2/#1 - When you click on the slider it will load new results using AJAX into a div. When i chose certain prices on the slider the results look fine in IE and when i chose other prices the results come back all broken.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Any javascript errors popping up when you load the prices with broken results?

Comment: give us a hand here... what IE version, and what slider values cause the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of invalid markup in the HTML fragment that comes back from the slider actions. You've got some unclosed tags, etc.

Example:

```
    <div style="background-color:#252525; padding:5px 10px; height:130px; position:relative;">

        <p class="bold" style="color:#8a96a4; margin-bottom:0.5em;">Blue Lucerne lotus jug</p>

        <p class="bold" style="color:#FFF; margin-bottom:0.5em;">&pound;4250</p>

        <p style="margin-bottom:0.5em;"><p><strong>Superb and very rare 30cm lotus jug in the bl&hellip;</p>

        <p class="boldred" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:10px;"><a href="http://andrew-muir.com/stock/528/blue-lucerne-lotus-jug/">View details &gt;</a></p>

    </div>
```

That line with the "Superb and rare" text has an unclosed `<strong>` tag.

When I try to look at the broken page in the IE 8 developer tool, it won't show me the content of the main `<div>`.  That's a sure sign that the browser has just thrown up its hands in frustration.

*edit* — weird; it just started working ...

Comment: Yes it's pretty complicated markup and it was making me dizzy to stare at it for very long :-)  Also the fact that the script embedded in the returned block is a jQuery "ready" handler was making me pretty nervous too.  It'd be better for the script to be part of the main page, which would then just invoke it when the ajax operation completes.

Comment: Thanks for your time, it was the invalid html which was doing it. The text had come from a database and was truncated so the closing tag had been chopped off. I just needed to strip all tags out before putting it on the page. Looks like i worked it out and edited the page while you were looking at it.

Comment: Cool!  That all looked like really nice stuff for sale, by the way :-)